# when importing the opencv sample of facedetection in Android Studio, error openCVSamplefacedetection:compileArmDebugNdk occur

Tags: android, android-studio, opencv, android-ndk, java-native-interface

Error:Execution failed for task ':openCVSamplefacedetection:compileArmDebugNdk'.

> com.android.ide.common.internal.LoggedErrorException: Failed to run command:
>       D:\OpenCV-2.4.10-android-sdk\android-ndk-r10d\ndk-build.cmd NDK_PROJECT_PATH=null APP_BUILD_SCRIPT=E:\android_project\CastorYan\AndroidStudioProjects\face-detection\openCVSamplefacedetection\build\intermediates\ndk\arm\debug\Android.mk APP_PLATFORM=android-14 NDK_OUT=E:\android_project\CastorYan\AndroidStudioProjects\face-detection\openCVSamplefacedetection\build\intermediates\ndk\arm\debug\obj NDK_LIBS_OUT=E:\android_project\CastorYan\AndroidStudioProjects\face-detection\openCVSamplefacedetection\build\intermediates\ndk\arm\debug\lib APP_ABI=armeabi
>   Error Code:
>       2
>   Output:
>       make.exe: *** No rule to make target `E:\android_project\CastorYan\AndroidStudioProjects\face-detection\openCVSamplefacedetection\build\intermediates\ndk\arm\debug\obj/local/armeabi/objs/detection_based_tracker/E_\android_project\CastorYan\AndroidStudioProjects\face-detection\openCVSamplefacedetection\src\main\jni', needed by`E:\android_project\CastorYan\AndroidStudioProjects\face-detection\openCVSamplefacedetection\build\intermediates\ndk\arm\debug\obj/local/armeabi/objs/detection_based_tracker/E_\android_project\CastorYan\AndroidStudioProjects\face-detection\openCVSamplefacedetection\src\main\jni\DetectionBasedTracker_jni.o'.  Stop.

Comment: I have answered the solution in this [post][1]. Hope this help you.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/28879280/4193991