# ndk.dir error in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, opencv, android-studio, android-ndk

I was trying to use opencv library, so I imported one of its projects in Android Studio and when I tried to run it I got this error:

> Error:Execution failed for task ':openCVSamplefacedetection:compileDebugNdk'.
>   NDK not configured.
>   Download the NDK from http://developer.android.com/tools/sdk/ndk/.Then add ndk.dir=path/to/ndk in local.properties.
>   (On Windows, make sure you escape backslashes, e.g. C:\ndk rather than C:\ndk)

So I downloaded the ndk and I addes this line to the local.properties file where it became:

```
sdk.dir=C\:\\Users\\skoon\\AppData\\Local\\Android\\sdk
ndk.dir=C\:\\Users\\skoon\\AppData\\Roaming\\IDM\\android-ndk-r10d
```

but I still got this error which I didn't understand:

> Error:Execution failed for task ':openCVSamplefacedetection:compileDebugNdk'.
>   com.android.ide.common.internal.LoggedErrorException: Failed to run command:
>       C:\Users\skoon\AppData\Roaming\IDM\android-ndk-r10d\ndk-build.cmd NDK_PROJECT_PATH=null APP_BUILD_SCRIPT=C:\Users\skoon\Downloads\Compressed\OpenCV-2.4.10-android-sdk\OpenCV-2.4.10-android-sdk\samples\face-detection\openCVSamplefacedetection\build\intermediates\ndk\debug\Android.mk APP_PLATFORM=android-14 NDK_OUT=C:\Users\skoon\Downloads\Compressed\OpenCV-2.4.10-android-sdk\OpenCV-2.4.10-android-sdk\samples\face-detection\openCVSamplefacedetection\build\intermediates\ndk\debug\obj NDK_LIBS_OUT=C:\Users\skoon\Downloads\Compressed\OpenCV-2.4.10-android-sdk\OpenCV-2.4.10-android-sdk\samples\face-detection\openCVSamplefacedetection\build\intermediates\ndk\debug\lib APP_ABI=all
>   Error Code:
>       2
>   Output:
>       make.exe: *** No rule to make target 'C:\Users\skoon\Downloads\Compressed\OpenCV-2.4.10-android-sdk\OpenCV-2.4.10-android-sdk\samples\face-detection\openCVSamplefacedetection\build\intermediates\ndk\debug\obj/local/arm64-v8a/objs/detection_based_tracker/C_\Users\skoon\Downloads\Compressed\OpenCV-2.4.10-android-sdk\OpenCV-2.4.10-android-sdk\samples\face-detection\openCVSamplefacedetection\src\main\jni', needed by `C:\Users\skoon\Downloads\Compressed\OpenCV-2.4.10-android-sdk\OpenCV-2.4.10-android-sdk\samples\face-detection\openCVSamplefacedetection\build\intermediates\ndk\debug\obj/local/arm64-v8a/objs/detection_based_tracker/C_\Users\skoon\Downloads\Compressed\OpenCV-2.4.10-android-sdk\OpenCV-2.4.10-android-sdk\samples\face-detection\openCVSamplefacedetection\src\main\jni\DetectionBasedTracker_jni.o'.  Stop.

I didn't change anything in the code, so what should I do? do I need to change or add any variables to point to the ndk?

P.S. This is my first time trying to build Android application so I don't have any experience.

Thank you in advance.

UPDATE:

To import the project I just used import project from file, then I synced the gardle, and run the project.
the package that I downloaded from opencv was the Android one, and I tried to use the face detection sample.
when I run it I got the error above.

Comment: What steps did you do to import "one of its projects" into Android Studio? Which tutorial did you follow? What is the configuration of the project? Please update your question with these details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to setup OpenCV librairies for your project. You can follow the instruction [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22427267/4481702).

Comment: Thank you so much I followed all of the instructions and no error appeared.

Answer (score 0):

OpenCV sample projects haven't support gradle officially. I think it will be easier if you start a new project and configure it to work as in examples.
I have implemented a tutorial project using Android Studio + NDK + OpenCV. You may have a look. https://github.com/quanhua92/NDK_OpenCV_AndroidStudio

Answer (score 0):

Install NDK in your SDK manager, if you already installed open app's "build.gradle" replace these lines

```
sourceSets { main { jni.srcDirs = ['src/main/jni', 'src/main/jniLibs/', 'src/main/jni/'] } }
```

to

`sourceSets.main {
        jniLibs.srcDir 'src/main/jniLibs' // mention your JNI lib path(where ".so" files contains) 
        jni.srcDirs = [] //disable automatic ndk-build call
    }`

I'm tried to configure OpenCV and its fixed